# Typescript timestamp get milliseconds

Tags: typescript, timestamp, difference

In my TypeScript project I get a response containing timestamps which looks like this:

- +049235-10-18T04:13:50.000Z

This timestamp can I convert into a LocaleString which then looks like this:

- 7.4.2017, 14:29:17

I want to get the difference between two Timestamps in seconds. The time difference between two Timestamps can be a few seconds or even days. Is there a solution for this in TypeScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use moment.js (http://momentjs.com/)

```
moment().subtract(Object);
```